# Migrated data using CSV, but having problem if I try to create Relationships using PERIODIC COMMIT

Tags: csv, neo4j, migration

I have created CSV from Postgresql and successfully uploaded 180 million records to Neo4j. After that, I have created Indices. But when I tried to create Relationship using PERIODIC COMMIT in cypher-shell. The script got stuck. Even I changed PERIODIC COMMIT to 10. What should be the remedy.

Comment: Can you add the query you are using for creating relationships?

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to answer as we haven't seen the query. But for me it sounds like you haven't an index that identifies the node for each the relation creation. May you can run your query with the explain keyword a single relationship like

```
explain 
match (n:Node {hasid:1}),(m:Node {hasid:2}) 
create (n)-[:REL]->(m)
```

and check if the query planer uses the index. If the query planer does not use the index change your query so that it is using the index. Otherwise it will take a very long time.

Comment: I have created index also.

Comment: Can you maybe provide more information e.g. code how you do it and how your queries look like?

Comment: CREATE INDEX ON :User(django_id);
CREATE INDEX ON :User(social_media_type);

CREATE INDEX ON :Post(django_id);
CREATE INDEX ON :Post(social_media_type);

//user owns Post (Twitter)
USING PERIODIC COMMIT 10000
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:/cyper_script/import/tweets1.csv" AS row
FIELDTERMINATOR ','
MATCH (tweet:Post) where tweet.user_id = toInteger(row.person_id) and tweet.share_of IS NULL
MATCH (tweet_owner:User) where tweet_owner.django_id = toInteger(row.person_id)
MERGE (tweet_owner)-[:OWNS]->(tweet);

Comment: As I said before i think it is an index problem because there is no  index on `Post(user_id)`. Additional you are using `toInteger(row.person_id) ` two times maybe it would be wise to use a with statement before to reduce the number of string to int conversions.